# Oracle SQL priority based pivot

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I would like to display a list of customer_ids with the top five addresses displayed as columns next to them based on the number of claims_count.  Is it possible using PIVOT?

```
CREATE TABLE pivot_test (
customer_id   NUMBER,
claims_count NUMBER,
address  VARCHAR2(5)
);

INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (1,23,'A');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (1,2,'B');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (1,43,'C');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (1,0,'D');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (1,34,'E');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (1,23,'F');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (2,6,'A');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (2,3,'B');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (2,67,'C');
COMMIT;
```

The desired Outcome would be something like:

```
customer_id    Address1    Address2    Address3    Address4    Address5
1                 C            E           A           F           B
2                 C            A           B
```

Comment: What is the "priority" in your title? Also, given the addresses, how do you decide which is Address1 and which is Address 2 etc. (or can it be random? Or is that related to the "priority" which you forgot to discuss?) And how do the values 'A', 'B' from your input become lower-case 'a' and 'b' in the output?

Comment: Thanks for calling that out, I'll work on updating the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `PIVOT`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        customer_id,
        address,
        row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by claims_count desc) rn
    from pivot_test t
)
pivot (
    max(address) for rn in (
        1 as Address1,
        2 as Address2,
        3 as Address3,
        4 as Address4,
        5 as Address5
    )
);
```

Demo:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from  (
  3    select
  4     customer_id,
  5     address,
  6     row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by claims_count desc) rn
  7    from pivot_test t
  8  )
  9  pivot (
 10    max(address) for rn in (
 11      1 as Address1,
 12      2 as Address2,
 13      3 as Address3,
 14      4 as Address4,
 15      5 as Address5
 16    )
 17  );

CUSTOMER_ID ADDRE ADDRE ADDRE ADDRE ADDRE
----------- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
          1 C     E     A     F     B
          2 C     A     B

SQL>
```

Comment: I added an additional requirement, thank you for your answer it worked perfectly for the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select customer_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then address end) as address_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then address end) as address_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then address end) as address_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then address end) as address_4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then address end) as address_5
from (select pt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by customer_id) as seqnum
      from pivot_test pt
     ) pt
group by customer_id;
```

Comment: `partition by customer_id` and then within each partition `order by customer_id`? What for? `order by null` would have the same effect and the meaning would be much clearer.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it did exactly what I wanted for the original question I asked.